# Probabilty Mass Function for runs scored in an over

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The probabilities of scoring 0, 1, 2, 4, and 6 runs on a given delivery in a cricket match are 0.4, 0.35, 0.15,  0.075 and 0.025 respectively. Assuming that the probabilities of a wicket, a wide ball and a no-ball are zero, obtain the probability mass function, and the mean, maximun, minimum and most probable number of runs in one over.

Do we have to calculate the PMF for all values of runs possible between 0 to 36 or is their a generalized way to do this?

I am new to Probability and Statistics!

Comment: Sorry, what's an "over"?

Comment: an over consists of 6 balls/deliveries. At each ball you can score 0 run, 1 run, 2 runs, 4 runs or 6 runs... I hope this helps!

Comment: So...the min and max over an over, so to speak, are easy to identify.  For the mean...well, it's easy enough to compute for one delivery and after that it is additive.  For the exact distribution I think you need to write it out.  Comes down to partitions of the desired score (you can get $12$ runs by two $6's$ or a $4$ and four $2's$ and so on).  Don't see an easy way out...

Comment: Generating functions can help with the counting.  Well, they can help organize the count.  That's important...if you list cases by hand it is sometimes hard to be sure you got them all.  Here's a good reference:  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/GeneratingFunctions.shtml .  In this case, we define $\phi(x)=\sum p_i x^i$ where $p_i$ is the probability of getting exactly $i$ runs on a single delivery.  Then you are after the coefficients in $\phi(x)^6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:  a (somewhat more expedient) way to get the exact distribution is to use generating functions.  In this case we define:  $$\phi(x)=.4+.35x+.15x^2+.075x^4+.025x^6$$

Then the probability that you will get exactly $i$ runs in $6$ deliveries is the coefficient of $x^i$ in $\phi(x)^6$ (assuming independence, of course). Wolfram alpha helpfully computes this polynomial for us; we get:   $$.004096+.021504x+.056256x^2+.0952x^3+.119823x^4+.12475x^5+.118316x^6+.107049x^7+.0926777x^8+.0754763x^9+.0579852x^{10}+.0422615x^{11}+.0298725x^{12}+.0204094x^{13}+.0135278x^{14}+.00853535x^{15}+.00525483x^{16}+.00309094x^{17}+.00180783x^{18}+.000998115x^{19}+.000553093x^{20}+.000279241x^{21}+.000149001x^{22}+.0000685986x^{23}+.0000362278x^{24}+.0000145605x^{25}+7.84131*10^{-6}x^{26}+2.46094*10^{-6}x^{27}+1.57104*10^{-6}x^{28}+3.07617*10^{-7}x^{29}+2.87109*10^{-7}x^{30}+2.05078*10^{-8}x^{31}+4.1748*10^{-8}x^{32}+4.39453*10^{-9}x^{34}+2.44141*10^{-10}x^{36}$$

Just out of curiosity:  why is it impossible to get $3$ or $5$ runs?

Comment: He has written in the question that probability of a wide ball and no ball is zero. So 3 or 5 runs is not possible. You've to know the rules of cricket ;)

Comment: @math_noob   So, is it just definitional?  As in "no single play in American football can score $4$ points."... Makes sense, of course.  Just that when I hear "runs" I think in terms of baseball.  right.  I'll look up the rules.  thanks!

Comment: oops my bad. Actually 3 runs is possible even with the assumptions given in the question. I think he just omitted them to simplify things.

Comment: @math_noob Full disclosure: many people have tried to explain the rules of cricket to me in the past. No luck.  Kind of sad, really.  But then I have never been able to explain, say, the Infield Fly rule to anyone who didn't grow up with it.

Comment: It has been just omitted to simplify the questions... Thanks!